# Can i combine the ls command with -R and a specific type of file (.txt)

Tags: linux, bash

I just started using bash programming (if its called that way) a week ago for university so im at rock bottom oops...

The task is to search our computer for .pdf, .txt and .docx files and count them.

Im looking for a way to combine the command

```
ls **.txt | wc -l
```

with the command

```
ls -R | wc -l
```

I tried combinations of the two commands:

```
ls -R **.txt | wc -l
```

```
ls **.txt -R | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

A bash-only solution has already been given, but I'd like to point you at `find` which is a great tool for this kind of job. For example:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.docx'
```

Comment: [Do learn `find`.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) It is the best, and sometimes only, answer to *a lot* of problems. Make sure you familiarize yourself with its `-exec` and `-execdir` features, and remember to use those instead *whenever* you feel like looping over some list of files...

Answer (score 1):

To have `**` interpreted as any hierarchy of sub-directories you must enable the `globstar` option: `shopt -s globstar`. Then, you should `ls **/*.txt`, not `ls **.txt`. Note that `ls` is usually not what you want for scripting. Prefer:

```sh
$ shopt -s globstar nullglob
$ files=(**/*.txt)
$ echo "${#files[@]}"
124
```

The `nullglob` option is useful in case you have no `txt` files. Without it `**/*.txt` would expand as the literal `**/*.txt` string and you would get a count of 1. While with `nullglob` enabled it expands as the empty string.

`files=(**/*.txt)` stores the list of files in an indexed bash array named `files`. `${#files[@]}` expands as the number of elements in array `files`.